# Query holds on to old criteria & Subform won't refresh

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm currently working on redesigning my company's access database from scratch, with no prior experience, because the last edits to its structure were made in 2006, and it's basically a list with 200k records that's slow ass hell. (current tests with working features are already showing significant improvements, yay!)

I tried to create a subform that displays the result of a query, but the query itself depends on a multiselect. The query acts on a customer Id and returns results based on the selected customers. (this works)

I've been looking and searching for a solution, but, i just can't figure out what to do.
The problem i'm dealing with is twofold, and i suspect related, but first a little bit of context.

First of all, the subform just refuses to update visually. While the query holds the desired results, the subform doesn't update at all, i've tried refresh, docmd.requery, you name it, the only thing that works is basically 'reattaching' the source. Any manner that managed to refresh the shown results are not accessible from the 'surface'.

Second, the query seems to 'hold on' to whatever clients were previously selected. Even though it can go from all clients (i have written this as a 'no selection means everything') to specific clients, in between selections, it keeps the criteria from the previous selection, and brings them forward.

'Dashboard' is the form in which the subform TabGeneralSubform is nested , qryTetraGeneral is the query used as a source for the subform. MultiCustomer is the multiselect form.

```
Sub ListAll_Click() [access vba]


Set MyDB = CurrentDb
flgSelectAll = 0

Set qdef = MyDB.QueryDefs("qryTetraGeneral")

'strSQL is based on the SQL conversion of the SelectClientAll query
'the final AND clause will be appended by strWhere which is based on the MultiList Selection
'If there is no selection the query will default to All active Subs

 strSQL = "SELECT [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI,[EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI, [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active," & _
    " [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation, Client_Table.[Customer Name], Client_Table.[Customer ID], [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ReqType, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM," & _
    " SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQDATE, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.RESPUSER" & _
    " FROM ((Client_Table INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_ISSI] ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index])" & _
    " INNER JOIN SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.Index) INNER JOIN ([EQ-TETRA_TEI]" & _
    " INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL] ON [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].TEI) ON (SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].Reqnum)" & _
    " AND ([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ISSI)" & _
    " WHERE ((([EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI)=[EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].[TEI]) AND (([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active)=True) AND (([EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation)=True) AND ("

'extracts selection from list and creates SQL line to be added to strSQL

 For i = 0 To MultiCustomer.ListCount - 1
    If MultiCustomer.Selected(i) Then
        flgSelectAll = flgSelectAll + 1
        strIN = strIN & "([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index]=" & MultiCustomer.Column(0, i) & ")" & " OR "
    End If
 Next

 If flgSelectAll = 0 Then
    strSQL = "SELECT [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI,[EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI, [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active," & _
    " [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation, Client_Table.[Customer Name], Client_Table.[Customer ID], [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ReqType, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM," & _
    " SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQDATE, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.RESPUSER" & _
    " FROM ((Client_Table INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_ISSI] ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index])" & _
    " INNER JOIN SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.Index) INNER JOIN ([EQ-TETRA_TEI]" & _
    " INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL] ON [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].TEI) ON (SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].Reqnum)" & _
    " AND ([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ISSI)" & _
    " WHERE ((([EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI)=[EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].[TEI]) AND (([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active)=True) AND (([EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation)=True)) ORDER BY [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI;"
Else
    strWhere = Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 3) & ")) ORDER BY [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI;"
    strSQL = strSQL + strWhere
End If

qdef.SQL = strSQL
Call CallRefreshForm([Forms]![Dashboard])

For Each ListObject In MultiCustomer.ItemsSelected
    MultiCustomer.Selected(ListObject) = False
Next ListObject
```

Now, admittedly, the code is a bit cobbled together from what my predecessors left behind, and the SQL statement looks like a mess, however, it works and displays the desired results based on the criteria, which currently, is good enough for me. I'll probably try trimming it down later when i know all desired features are working.

Comment: Check what `Debug.Print strSQL` shows you at the point you do `qdef.SQL = strSQL`  Is it what you expect based on the selected customer indices?  And if you do `DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryTetraGeneral"`, does it return the correct data?

Comment: HansUp , the SQL string is what I expect it to be, except that it seems to take forward the criteria from the previous excecution of the SQL statement. I.e you look for customer A, then afterwards, you select a different customer, B, excecute the VBA code, but both A & B are displayed. My predecessor 'solved' this by basically deleting the query and then using CreateQueryDef. However, that caused some annoying bugs in my use case and i figured there might be a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that this can be streamlined. Firstly when you build the SQL based on the list box, rather than use a lot of `IN/OR`, just use `IN` once (I'm air-coding a bit here, so forgive any slight errors)

```
For i = 0 To MultiCustomer.ListCount - 1
    If MultiCustomer.Selected(i) Then
        strSQL = strSQL & MultiCustomer.Column(0, i) & "," 
    End If
Next i
If Right(strSQL,1)="," Then strSQL=Left(strSQL,Len(strSQL)-1)
If Len(strSQL)>0 Then
    strSQL="SELECT [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI,[EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI, [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active," & _
    " [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation, Client_Table.[Customer Name], Client_Table.[Customer ID], [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ReqType, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM," & _
    " SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQDATE, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.RESPUSER" & _
    " FROM ((Client_Table INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_ISSI] ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index])" & _
    " INNER JOIN SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.Index) INNER JOIN ([EQ-TETRA_TEI]" & _
    " INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL] ON [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].TEI) ON (SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].Reqnum)" & _
    " AND ([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ISSI)" & _
    " WHERE [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI=[EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].[TEI] " _
    & " AND [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active=True " _
    & " AND [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation=True " _
    & " AND [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index] IN (" & strSQL & ")
Else
    strSQL="SELECT [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI,[EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI, [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active," & _
    " [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation, Client_Table.[Customer Name], Client_Table.[Customer ID], [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ReqType, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM," & _
    " SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQDATE, SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.RESPUSER" & _
    " FROM ((Client_Table INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_ISSI] ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].[Customer Index])" & _
    " INNER JOIN SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE ON Client_Table.[External Customer Index] = SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.Index) INNER JOIN ([EQ-TETRA_TEI]" & _
    " INNER JOIN [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL] ON [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].TEI) ON (SERVICEREQUEST_TABLE.REQNUM = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].Reqnum)" & _
    " AND ([EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI = [EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].ISSI)" & _
    " WHERE [EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI=[EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].[TEI] " _
    & " AND [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].Active=True " _
    & " AND [EQ-TETRA_TEI].Activation=True "
End If
strSQL=strSQL & " ORDER BY [EQ-TETRA_ISSI].ISSI;"
```

I'm also not convinced that you need to have `[EQ-TETRA_TEI].TEI=[EQ-TETRA_REQFUL].[TEI]` in the `WHERE` clause, as you are already using it to join two tables together.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll look at your suggestions for streamlining. I initially tried to use in ('@','@'), but i got criteria mismatch errors, i presume because it considers the arguments of IN as strings, and my indices are numbers, using 'OR' in the way i did, seemed to have solved that problem.